# Let $f$ be strictly increasing function. Can we say that $f^{-1}$ is strictly decreasing function?

Tags: calculus

Let $f:[0,\infty)\to[0,\infty)$ be strictly increasing function.
Can we say that $f^{-1}$ is  strictly decreasing function?

Comment: Have you tried any examples? What happens if $f(x)=x$?

Comment: Absolutely not.  The inverse needs to get you back to x.  x is increasing so you don't want the inverse to *shrink*! That'd get you *away* from x! You *need* the inverse to increase as well.  Increase in exact sychronization but inverse *steepness*  (**NOT** actual values).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, in fact $f^{-1} $ must also be increasing.

Let $f (x)=w$ and $f (y) =z$

Then $x < y \iff f (x) < f (y) $ so $f^{-1}(w) < f^{-1}(z) \iff w < z $.

So if $f $ is strictly increasing so is $f^{-1} $.

Comment: Also $f^{-1}$ is only defined on the domain $D=\{f(x); x\in dom(f)\}. $ E.g. when $f:R\to R$ with $f(x)=x$ for $x<q$ and $f(x)=x+1$ for $x\geq 1,$  so $D=(-\infty, 1)\cup [2,\infty).$

Answer (score 4):

No let $f(x)=x$. Then the inverse is........

Comment: Wont he  inverse start to decrease like 1/2 then 1/3/. So, its a decreasing function.

Comment: No, the inverse is increasing everywhere.

Comment: How? It is 0.5 then 0.3 then so on. Its tending to zero.

Comment: The inverse is just itself.

Comment: Can you kindly explain sir? I am not getting your point.

Comment: $y=x$ the identity function it is it's own inverse, hence when either x or y increase so does the other variable, hence both the function and it's inverse are strictly increasing

Comment: The inverse of a function is a function $f^{-1}$ such that $f\circ f^{-1}= f^{-1}\circ f= id$. So the inverse of identity is identity.

Comment: I think he means the inverse as $\frac1f$, not $f^{-1}$.

Comment: $f\circ g \ne f * g $.  $f^{-1}\circ f (x)=x $.  So if $f (x) = x $ then $f^{-1}(x)=f^{-1}(f (x))=x$.  You are thinking $\frac 1 {f(x)} * f (x) = 1$.

Comment: Another counter example.  $f (x) = x^2$.  Then $f ^{-1}(x)=\sqrt {x} $.  Both are strictly increasing.

Comment: 1/f (x) is not the inverse by any definition.  $f^{-1}(x) \ne (f (x))^{-1}=1/f (x) $.  That's not what the notation means.  But yes, if f is increasing, then 1/f is decreasing.  But that has *nothing* to do with inverses.

Answer (score 2):

By $f^{-1}$, do you mean the inverse or the reciprocal of $f$? If you're talking about the inverse, then no - the identity function is strictly increasing and is its own inverse. If you're talking about the reciprocal, then yes (though it gets weird if $f(x) = 0$). This is because $\frac{1}{a} > \frac{1}{b}$ if and only if $a < b$.